# How can I run this loops in robot framework?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop, robotframework

How can I run IF statement from bottom in romot framework?

```
(while i!=500:/ i = i + 1)
```

How can I execute python code as I tried to do on the bottom of my code?

```
*** Settings ***
Library  SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***
${Browser}  Chrome
${URL}  https://safeweb.aec.cz/level12.php
*** Test Cases ***
MYbot prihlas_kopiruj_stlac
    Open Browser  ${URL}  ${Browser}
    Input Text  name:login  name
    Input Text  name:password  pwd
    Click Button  submit
    go to  ${URL}

while i!=500:
    ${get_text}=  Get Text  //*[@id="cid"]
    Input Text  name:captcha  ${get_text}
    Click Button  ok
    i = i + 1
```

I tried to do it this way but it's complaining

> FOR loop contains no keywords

I just never used this way of coding loops (and I'm also supposed that this module is not using classical loops like in others programming languages).

```
: FOR  ${i}  IN RANGE  1  500
        ${get_text}=  Get Text  //*[@id="cid"]
        Input Text  name:captcha  ${get_text}
        Click Button  ok
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found out solution

```
: FOR  ${i}  IN RANGE  1  500
    \   ${get_text}=  Get Text  //*[@id="cid"]
    \   Input Text  name:captcha  ${get_text}
    \   Click Button  ok
```

this way it's working

Answer (score 2):

I do not know which version of Robot Framework you use, but I suggest upgrading to 3.1 as they have cleaned up the for [loop syntax](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/blob/master/doc/releasenotes/rf-3.1.rst#for-loop-enhancements) there a little bit.

While the one you have mentioned in your answer is still supported, a much nicer syntax has been added:

```
FOR  ${i}  IN RANGE  1  500
    ${get_text}=  Get Text  //*[@id="cid"]
    Input Text  name:captcha  ${get_text}
    Click Button  ok
END
```

You do not need the `:` and all those `\`, and the end of the loop body is marked explicitly as well.